# SUPEE 7405 and Cannot Remove the Cart Item

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, patch

Basically I got this problem after SUPEE 7405 update. Whenever I add something to the cart and then click remove item in the AJAX cart, it tells me "Cannot remove the item."

I have to refresh the page and then the item successfully removes.
Basically adding and then instantly removing item=Doesnt work., I need to add, refresh page (or go the other page of site) and then click remove.

i noticed the patch overrode 
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

Code before the patch

```
/**
 * Delete shoping cart item action
 */
public function deleteAction()
{
    $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($id) {
        try {
            $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
              ->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
}
```

Code after the patch

```
  /**
 * Delete shoping cart item action
 */
public function deleteAction()
{
    if ($this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
                    ->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
    }

    $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
}
```

What did the patch override in my files causing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update cart item template [design_package/theme]/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

Find `<a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove Item')) ?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></a>`

Replace with

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>form_key/<?php echo $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove Item')) ?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution. But it doesnt seem to work in my case as I have ajax installed. I have opened a different topic explaining the facing issue with sidebar cart delete button.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103764/supee-7405-add-form-key-to-sidebar-default-phtml

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the deleteAction function, SUPEE7405 added form-key validation to cart deletions to prevent malicious cross-site requests. If you've overridden the cart item template (checkout/cart/item/default.phtml) in your theme, or are using a theme which overrides this template, it will need to be updated to include the formkey hidden input field. You can pull the relevant change across from `base/default/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`.

Comment: Could you please tell me which form-key exactly/Which code should I use? (I am still learning) :)

Comment: If you open up the file I linked to (`base/default/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`) and the version in your current theme, then compare the "delete" button, you'll notice that the one in base/default has a different HTML structure, using an onclick attribute which includes the form key. That's what you need to add into your version of the template to remain consistent with the patched controller.

Comment: Great, I will try and reply with results :)

Comment: I just tried it, I do see that delete lines are slightly different in base/default/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml and MYTHEME/default/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml., but the same error appears "Cannot remove the item."

Comment: Base file delete action code:     <td class="a-center"><a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?></a></td>
MYTHEME file delete code: <td class="a-center"><a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('delete')?>" class="btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('delete')?></a></td>

Answer (score -2):

In my case Compilation was enabled. so i realized that compiled files wasnt compatible or recognized new patch (SUPEE 7405)

What did I do?

1. Remove patch `sh patch_name.sh -R`
2. Disable compilation
3. Clear magento cache
4. Apply patch again `sh patch_name.sh`
5. Clear magento cache again
6. Enable compilation
7. Run Compilation process

I hope that helps

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't help, my compilation is Disabled anyways. Thanks for idea!